Step Functions DynamoDB Query Task Missing in CDK?
I'm currently designing a Step Function in the AWS Console and using the DynamoDB Query task. However, when I tried adding the same design to my CDK app (using aws-cdk-lib version ^2.147.0), I couldn't find the Query task in the CDK. Even the documentation only seems to mention CRUD operations (like GetItem, PutItem, UpdateItem, etc.), but no reference to Query.
Is the ability to use Step Functions -> DynamoDB -> Query so new that it's not yet supported in CDK? Or am I missing something?
Just to clarify, GetItem isn't a solution for me because I don’t have the Sort Key value at the time of execution.
Thanks in advance!

I've got to use aws sdk integration, Query task isn't optimised.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.CallAwsService.html
